# $y'(x)=\sin(x+y(x))$, with $y(\frac{-\pi}2)=0$ - stuck at placing the initial condition at the general result $y(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the ODE $y'(x)=\sin(x+y(x))$, with the initial condition $y(\frac{-\pi}2)=0$.

I solved the general ODE by writing $t=x+y$ and then solving the equation $x=\int \frac{dt}{\sin t+1}$, getting $$x=\frac{-2}{\tan(\frac{x+y}{2})+1}+c$$
But when I try to plug in the initial condition $(-\frac{\pi}2,0)$ to find c, I get $0$ in the numerator.

How do I continue from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide by a term that can assume the value zero, you should always check that you do not lose a solution that way. Considering the initial conditions, the equation $1+\sin t=0$ has the solution $t=-\frac\pi2$ and thus
$$
y(x)=-x-\frac\pi2
$$
which is indeed a solution of the IVP complementing the family of solutions of the ODE found by the separation approach.